# Why is `gulp-ng-html2js` generating a js file for html code?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, gulp

I am trying to use gulp to help me minify and uglify html code. However, the example at https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-html2js seems to concatenate html code into a js file. I don't understand what javascript has to do with minified and uglified html code.

Can someone kindly explan this to me.

```
var ngHtml2Js = require("gulp-ng-html2js");
var minifyHtml = require("gulp-minify-html");
var concat = require("gulp-concat");
var uglify = require("gulp-uglify");

gulp.src("./partials/*.html")
    .pipe(minifyHtml({
        empty: true,
        spare: true,
        quotes: true
    }))
    .pipe(ngHtml2Js({
        moduleName: "MyAwesomePartials",
        prefix: "/partials"
    }))

    // js file from html code???
    .pipe(concat("partials.min.js"))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/partials"));
```

Comment: `gulp-ng-html2js` = *A Gulp plugin which generates AngularJS modules, which pre-load your HTML code into the $templateCache. This way AngularJS doesn't need to request the actual HTML files anymore.*

Comment: Yes, I read that... but I am not sure that I completely comprehend that.... mind explaining?

Comment: If you just want to minify/concat don't use this

Comment: @Weedoze I presume it should be okay to simply use `gulp-minify-html` and `gulp-uglify`... but what about `gulp-concat`?